# How to develop a Simple data entry form with 3 to 4 questions in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, list, development

I want to do below tasks and need your suggestions:

1.Create a simple data entry form with 3 to 4 questions with one attachment and save data into a custom list

2. when user open the data entry form name of the logged in user must be display in Name field
3. one user can enter multiple list items in list.
4. Site administrator can able to do sort by username and exports data into excel

Answer (score 0):

For your requirements, you can simply [create a custom list in SharePoint](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-list-0d397414-d95f-41eb-addd-5e6eff41b083#ID0EADAAA=Classic).

Add all necessary questions (columns) in list & then customize default list forms to auto populate the current user details.

Check below reference for auto populating user name in list forms:

[Auto Populate Current User Login Name in SharePoint](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/auto-populate-current-user-login-name-in-sharepoint1)

To add attachments to list items, make sure [attachments are enabled in list](https://global-sharepoint.com/sharepoint-online/disable-or-enable-attachments-to-list-items-in-sharepoint-online/).

By default one user can add multiple entries in list & users can sort the data as well as can [export it in excel](https://sharepointmaven.com/export-sharepoint-excel/).